# Why can't I add any new screenshots to media manager on iTunes Connect?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, media-manager

I tried to switch and delete languages for my app in iTunes Connect. After deleting old screenshots it seems that I locked my self out. I guess the new buggy Media Manager refers to some old screenshots that do not exist anymore. 12.9 inch display says it uses screenshots from " 12.9 inch display", which makes no sense. So I guess the linked screenshots are gone and I can't do anything about it.

Is there any trick? I can not add any new primary language as workaround because it throws a screenshot error.

Edit:
The first batch of screenshots was added before the media manager was introduced.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is an application support question. Nothing to do with programming.

Comment: Maybe post to Super User, or open a support ticket. But StackOverflow isn't the place for this type of question.

Comment: Since this a part of the annoying process of developing an iOS app, I thought this the right place to post it. I think other devs have to deal with the same problems.

Comment: Maybe so but... it's *not a programming question.*

Comment: Same problem here. Apple dev forum discussion: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/54168